# Scalable Solution to Width resizing?

Tags: html, css, width, responsiveness

This is a project from hell. Obviously, it's one I inherited from a previous dev team, with the "simple" task of making sure the width of a particular div scales in proportion of its intended container. In full width, everything looks fine, but of course, after it hits its first breakpoint, the whole div gets pushed into it's neighboring sidebar.

Messing with the width values proves to solve the issue, however setting up media queries for all the inane breakpoints of this particular site will be something of a nightmare ( read: a total nightmare ). The guys who passed this onto me don't understand that, however there is something they're correct about-- this issue is site wide, and if solved in one location, will likely reverberate down and resolve various issues across the site.

Has anyone run into a similar issue as this and found a scalable solution to calculating width values based on the viewport size while letting the inherit width values take care of resizing based on screen size, or am I going to have to make a bunch of media queries to resolve this issue like I'm fearing? I could get it done if that were the case, however I'm definitely open to suggestions for alternatives.

This is the CSS for the parent div:

```
float: left; 
padding: 10px 20px; 
width: 800px;
```

This is the CSS for it's neighboring sidebar:

```
float: left; 
width: 200px;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use percentages for width?

Comment: Setting percentages on the sidebar skews it pretty brutally, however using percentages on it's neighboring div works well.

However, setting max-width to 800px and width to 90% still doesn't scale appropriately, and the neighboring divs conflict.

Comment: Can you include a minimal snippet here that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I think i've got it-- the parent container of everything didn't have a mix-width value. Setting that made the % values actually work.